# Assign a managed identity access to an application role using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-managed-identity

I want to assign a managed identity access to an application role using Terraform.

I found a similar procedure, but it uses PowerShell. I want to do that with Terraform.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-assign-app-role-managed-identity-powershell

```
resource "azuread_application_app_role" "AppRole1" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.ResourceController.id
  allowed_member_types  = ["Application"]
  description           = "All access"
  display_name          = "All access"
  is_enabled            = true
  value                 = "All"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "assignment1" {
  principal_id = data.azuread_service_principal.website.id # This is a managed identity.
  role_definition_id = azuread_application_app_role.AppRole1.id
  scope= azuread_application_app_role.ResourceController.id # ???
}
```

What should I specify in the scope field or this isn't possible with Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope is the resource Id that you want to assign the managed identity with the role. For example, you want to assign the managed identity to the VM with the role you create. Then the scope is the VM resource ID like this:

```
"/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/group_name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm_name"
```

Comment: If the target is a VM or other Azure resources, it works. In this case the access target is an app role.

Comment: @Wakusei OK, but if you want to assign the app role, then the `azurerm_role_assignment` resource can't achieve it. You need to create the resource `azuread_application` by configuring the [`app_role`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application#app_role) attribute.

Comment: An app role can be created with app_role or azuread_application_app_role. But both don't have role assignemnt.

Comment: @Wakusei I mean you can create the app role through the resource `azuread_application_app_role` and then create the resource `azuread_application` by configuring the `app_role` attribute to assign the app role to the application. There is no separate assignment for the app role.

Comment: In this case the access source is a managed identity.

Comment: @Wakusei Then you can't achieve it through Terraform. The resource `azurerm_role_assignment` only can be used to assign the Azure role with the scope of the resources in the subscription. Not for the AD. And in Terraform AD resources, there is no app role assignment.

Comment: @Wakusei What you can do is to execute the PowerShell command in the Terraform code, and this is the only way to achieve it through Terraform.

Comment: @Wakusei Though you also need to run the PowerShell command, it's still a workaround in Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

It might be impossible with the current Terraform Azure provider.

I found this comment on a GitHub issue.

> azurerm_role_assignment can be used only to assign role to
> Subscription Resources.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6557#issuecomment-658154929

Comment: This is the same as I said in the comment. But it does not mean you can't do it through Terraform. Read my comment carefully!